# Javafx method for finding TreeItem by value returning null

Tags: java, javafx, treeview, javafx-8

I have created a method for searching a JavaFX TreeView and returning the TreeItem that matches a given value but it returns a TreeView with a value of null. I have added a couple of sysouts and it does correctly find the TreeItem but it still returns an empty one.

```
    public void addDirToTree(Directory parentDir, Directory newDir) {
        TreeItem<Label> parentTreeItem = findTreeItemByName(this.getRoot(),parentDir.getName());
        System.out.println(parentTreeItem);
        parentTreeItem.getChildren().add(createTreeItem(newDir));
    }
    
    
    private static TreeItem<Label> findTreeItemByName(TreeItem<Label> parentTreeItem, String name) {        
        for (TreeItem<Label> treeItem: parentTreeItem.getChildren()) {
            if (treeItem.getValue().getText().equals(name)) {
                System.out.println(treeItem);
                return treeItem;
            }
            findTreeItemByName(treeItem,name);
        }
        
        return parentTreeItem;
    }
```

Output:

```
TreeItem [ value: Label@402c2e44[styleClass=label]'new' ]
TreeItem [ value: null ]
```

These methods are inside a class that extends TreeView which is why `this.getRoot()` is passed

Comment: Don't you mean `return findTreeItemByName(...)` as your recursive step, and `return null;` if nothing is found? Off-topic: why do you have a `TreeItem<Label>`? The `TreeItem` should wrap data, not UI elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand why you have a `TreeItem<Label>`. The intention is that `TreeItem` should wrap a piece of data, not a UI element.

Your recursion is incorrectly implemented. If the correct `TreeItem` is not found in the immediate descendants of the supplied `TreeItem`, you then recursively search the descendants of those items, but don't do anything with the any result you find, instead returning the originally-supplied item.

You need something like this:

```
private static TreeItem<String> findTreeItemByName(TreeItem<String> parentTreeItem, String name) {
    // if the supplied item is the one we're looking for, just return it:    
    if (parentTreeItem.getValue().equals(name)) {
        return parentTreeItem;
    }    
    // Recursively search child items and return one if found: 
    for (TreeItem<String> treeItem: parentTreeItem.getChildren()) {
        TreeItem<String> item = findTreeItemByName(treeItem,name);
        if (item != null) return item;
    }
    // We didn't find a match: return null:
    return null;
}
```

Comment: The first return in the if statement was supposed to return the found item and the second is if nothing is found return the original one which is the root. I'll give yours a go though thanks! And the TreeItem contains a label because the label has an onclick event action on it, that bit actually works ok I'm not too bothered by that.

Comment: @Michael *"the TreeItem contains a label because the label has an onclick event action on it"* You should register the listener with the tree cells. You should not have labels for every item in the tree, regardless of whether or not it is displayed. *"I'm not too bothered by that"* You should be.

Comment: But wouldn't that fire an onclick event when the tree item is expanded? The idea for this is that you can press the arrow to expand the treeitem or click the label to do another action.

Comment: @Michael. I don't believe so. The internal handler for the expand button should consume the event, if the expand button is actually part of the cell.